# Excluding objects from child scopes in AdminConfig.list (wsadmin)

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

In wsadmin I want to find the `JMSProvider` attached to a specific `Node`. However, there are many servers under the node which also have a provider of the same name. When I ask for a list of providers, I get the one from the current node, but also from all of the child nodes.

```
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('Node')
MELW46K962S_node(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node|node.xml#Node_1)
dmgr_node(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/dmgr_node|node.xml#Node_1)

wsadmin>print AdminConfig.list('JMSProvider', 'MELW46K962S_node(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node|node.xml#Node_1)')
... excluding those providers with a different name ...
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/app_01|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/profiled_app01|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/rep_01|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/rep_02|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/rep_03|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/server1|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node/servers/web_01|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider(cells/gmm_cell/nodes/MELW46K962S_node|resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider)"
```

Without having to parse the ID, is there a method I can use to find which of these `WebSphere MQ JMS Provider`s belongs to the node? (i.e. the last one, in this instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`AdminConfig.getId`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html#rxml_adminconfig1__cmd13) instead of `AdminConfig.list`:

```
AdminConfig.getid("/Node:%s/JMSProvider:/" % nodename).splitlines()
```

Note that in this case, the `nodename` should just be the name of the node (i.e. `MELW46K962S_node`), not the full configuration id for the node as obtained by `AdminConfig.list('Node')`.